# Can mod_rewrite distinguish between 'user' request and internal redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Simple question really.

After an internal redirect, the original 'context' is gone. I'd like to know if there is a variable or flag that allows me to check against the original request instead of the rewritten request. Pseudo code:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteRule .+ public/$0.html [L]

 RewriteCond %{WHAT_USER_TYPED} ^public/(.+)\.html
 RewriteRule .+ - [R=404,L]
```

In this example, when I type `mywebsite.com/slug` the request gets rewritten to path `public/slug.html`. Now, an internal redirect occurs and my path might match the second condition `public/(.+)\.html`, and returns a 404. That's not what I want. So, I'd like to know if there is some kind of solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another reason why you should avoid adding rewriterules in .htaccess files. If you would do this in the main server context you would not have this problem. In a directory context or .htaccess file each rewrite causes an internal subrequest.

There is a parameter that contains the original request, It's "%{THE_REQUEST}

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
RewriteRule (.*)                   public/$0.html?redir [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}        GET\ /public
RewriteRule .*                    - [R=404,L]
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it! Good tip on the difference between htaccess files and server config. I chose .htaccess since this problem was on a shared hosting server, but I may want to reconsider.

Comment: "each rewrite causes an internal subrequest" - This isn't strictly a "subrequest". The `IS_SUBREQ` server variable remains "false" and rules with `NS` (`nosubreq`) still trigger. It's still the same request, it's just that after a redirect/rewrite the "request process starts over".